# Navigation menu won't vertically align with logo image

Tags: html, css

Tried to vertically align my nav menu with my logo image but with the code I have the navbar doesn't even seem to be within the container element. Any specific error or is it multiple things?

```css
/* Body styles */

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1400px;
}


/* Header styles */

header {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 140px;
  height: 160px;
}

header img {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Navigation list styles */

header .container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1140px;
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

header .container .nav-logo {
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 188px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav.nav-right {
  min-width: 737.667px;
  width: 737.667px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-right ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-right li {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav-right li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-right li a:hover {
  outline: 1px black solid;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="site_logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=# alt="menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="locations">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="nutrition">Nutrition</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="our 
                        story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="rewards">Rewards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add a `display: inline-block` to your `header .container .nav-logo`

```css
/* Body styles */

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1400px;
}


/* Header styles */

header {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 140px;
  height: 160px;
}

header img {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Navigation list styles */

header .container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1140px;
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

header .container .nav-logo {
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 188px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav.nav-right {
  min-width: 737.667px;
  width: 737.667px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-right ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-right li {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav-right li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-right li a:hover {
  outline: 1px black solid;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="site_logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=# alt="menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="locations">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="nutrition">Nutrition</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="our story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="rewards">Rewards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can try inserting your image source line `nav-right` class,
as i don't see the css code for `nav-logo` class, else write the code for `nav-logo` class

```
.nav-logo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: right;
max-width:100%; // or your desired size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new css rule  **display: inline;**  for `.nav-logo{}`;

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/YQdKZY

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's the best practice, you can simply add `float: left;` to `header .container .nav-logo`

```
header .container .nav-logo {
 min-height: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 width: 188px;
 padding-top: 35px;
 float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vu8y4uxa/

Or as suggested elsewhere use display: `inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard, you use `float: right;` for `nav-right` but you forgot to use `float: left;` for `nav-logo` class. This will fix it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```css
/* Body styles */

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1400px;
}


/* Header styles */

header {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 140px;
  height: 160px;
}

header img {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Navigation list styles */

header .container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1140px;
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

header .container .nav-logo {
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 188px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;//Add this
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav.nav-right {
  min-width: 737.667px;
  /*width: 737.667px;*///Remove this
  /*float: right;*///Remove this
}

.nav-right ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-right li {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav-right li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-right li a:hover {
  outline: 1px black solid;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav-right">
      <div class="nav-logo"><!--Move this-->
        <img src="site_logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=# alt="menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="locations">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="nutrition">Nutrition</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="our 
                        story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="rewards">Rewards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and while it moved my navmenu up it messed with a majority of my css styling and despite me going back, it won't reload the code and update my page. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You can add this : `header .container .nav-logo{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;}`, your logo will be a the top left of your page. But it's not a responsiv solution.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use flexbox, which will also save you some CSS coding. For browser compatibility please check [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). The code suggested doesn't give any issues from IE11 onwards.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100&text=LOGO" alt="Site Logo" />
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=# alt="menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="locations">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="nutrition">Nutrition</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="our story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href=# alt="rewards">Rewards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Whilst flex box is definitely the cleaner and more modern way of doing things, make the OP aware of backward compatibility issues with using flexbox as older browser don't support it (from when I last checked)

Comment: @ Alex - Done. Thanks for the tip.